# Matlab num2str (A, format) function component-wise?

Tags: matlab

I have

```
    a=[0.221354766 315.806415];
```

I want sth like (same fieldwidth)

```
    0.2214     315.8064
```

I tried

```
    b=num2str(a) 
    % b =
    % 0.2213548      315.8064
    c=num2str(a,'%8.4f')
    % c =
    % 0.2214315.8064
    d=num2str(a,'%8.7g')
    %d =
    %0.2213548 315.8064
```

Any suggestion? Tks

Comment: you say you want the same field width but then show that you want the same number of decimal places, this is not the same thing, could you specify? Also do you want the output as strings or numbers?

Comment: `num2str` seems to eat the leading whitespace. Try your examples with [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

Comment: Tks. I tried `sprintf('%8.4g',a)`, but it didnt work well. I want [__0.2214, 315.8064], and it seems the same number of decimal places and same field width (including the whitespace) can not be met at the same time @Steve

Comment: I think you need an extra trailing whitespace to separate the numbers `'%8.4f '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the same number of decimal places? If this is the case, just leave off the first number in your format string:

```
num2str([0.221354766 315.806415],'%.4f ')

ans =

    '0.2214 315.8064'
```

Comment: Tks.I want [__0.2214, 315.8064], and it seems the same number of decimal places and same field width (including the whitespace) can not be met at the same time. Your approch shows no 2 characters whitespace before 0.2214@MrAzzaman

Comment: If you use `sprintf` instead, it should work, kind of. If you use `sprintf('%8.4f',a)`, you'll get `__0.2214315.8064`, because your last number is 8 characters long. If you used `9.4` instead, you'd have a space between them, i.e. `___0.2214_315.8064`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store these values as strings, then by all means use `num2str(a, '%.4f')`. It seems odd to take a numerical martrix and store all of the values as strings though, to just round the result use `round`

```
m = round([0.221354766 315.806415], 4)

>> m = [0.2214, 315.8064]
```